# Algorithm: Count the minimum number of distinct sorted subsequence for each update query

Tags: algorithm

This question is asked to me in an interview:
**Distinct sorted subsquence containing adjacent values** is defined as either its **length is one** or it only contains **adjacent numbers when sorted**. Each element can belong to only 1 such subsequence. I have Q queries, each updating a single value in A and I have to answer for each query, how many parts would be in the partition of A into distinct sorted subsequences if the number of parts was minimized.

For example, the number of parts for A = [1,2,3,4,3,5] can be minimized by partitioning it in the following two ways, both of which contain only two parts:

```
1) [1,2,3] && [4,3,5] ==> answer 2 (4,3,5 sorted is 3,4,5 all adjacent values)

2) [1,2,3,4,5] && [3] ==> answer 2
```

**Approach I tried:** Hashing and forming sets but all test cases were not cleared because of Timeout.

**Problem Statment PDF :** [PDF](https://expirebox.com/download/d250698abbe222861fe450d7f0ee6297.html)

**Constraints:**
`1<= N,Q <= 3*10^5`
`1< A(i)< 10^9`

Comment: I hope I never have to answer this question in an interview!

Comment: @Brien haha its too much time taking I know. But can't figure out if segment tree is applicable in some sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "queries" and "updation"?

Comment: @melpomene Query for minimum sets on some updation like A[v]=u

Comment: "updation" is not a word.

Comment: I made some edits to your question, trying to clarify the English. Please let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: I have a pretty simple O(n) solution, if radix sort is available. What guarantees do you have as to the range of values in the input collection? I am not downloading your pdf.

Comment: input collection 1<= ai <= 10^9

Comment: 1<= N and Q <= 3*10^5

Comment: Nevermind then, can't radix sort that. We need that number to be much less than N, and need to store that many counts. Although you should probably post the parameters -- for all I know, that is much less than N. For really huge N, a variation of radix sort gives a 2N answer, if you can store 10^9 numbers (and the counts don't overflow).

Comment: @KennyOstrom thanks. I know I cant use radix. for constraints i have given link to the PDF.

Comment: I recommend you do not try to require people to click an external link.

Comment: [Related meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preprocessing

First you can preprocess `A` before all queries and generate a table (say `times_of`) such that when given a number `n`, one can efficiently obtain the number of times `n` appears in `A` through expression like `times_of[n]`. In the following example assuming `A` is of type `int[N]`, we use an `std::map` to implement the table. Its construction costs O(NlogN) time.

```
auto preprocess(int *begin, int *end)
{
    std::map<int, std::size_t> times_of;
    while (begin != end)
    {
        ++times_of[*begin];
        ++begin;
    }
    return times_of;
}
```

Let `min` and `max` be the minimum and maximum elements of `A` respectively. Then the following lemma applies:

> The minimum number of distinct sorted subsequences is equal to max{0, `times_of[min]` - `times_of[min-1]`} + ... + max{0, `times_of[max]` -
>    `times_of[max-1]`}.

A rigorous proof is a bit technical, so I omit it from this answer. Roughly speaking, consider numbers from small to large. If `n` appears more than `n-1`, it has to bring extra `times_of[n]-times_of[n-1]` subsequences.

With this lemma, we can compute initially the minimum number of distinct sorted subsequences `result` in O(N) time (by iterating through `times_of`, not by iterating from `min` to `max`). The following is a sample code:

```
std::size_t result = 0;
auto prev = std::make_pair(min - 1, static_cast<std::size_t>(0));
for (auto &cur : times_of)
{
    // times_of[cur.first-1] == 0
    if (cur.first != prev.first + 1) result += cur.second;
    // times_of[cur.first-1] == times_of[prev.first]
    else if (cur.second > prev.second) result += cur.second - prev.second;

    prev = cur;
}
```

## Queries

To deal with a query `A[u] = v`, we first update `times_of[A[u]]` and `times_of[v]` which costs O(logN) time. Then according to the lemma, we need only to recompute constant (i.e. 4) related terms to update `result`. Each recomputation costs O(logN) time (to find the previous or next element in `times_of`), so a query takes O(logN) time in total.

Comment: can you explain your lemma a bit as : `times_of[min-1]` will be zero always. any code to compute it?

Comment: I want to check this algorithm.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Yes, I use `times_of[min-1]` instead of 0 for consistent of the formula.

Comment: can you check my implementation : [HERE](https://ideone.com/HGkh53) its calling abort. may be using too much resources

Comment: I have even not used `map` instead i used `unordered_map` for lowering down the complexity further. can we optimize it further

Comment: @OptimusPrime I have said "by iterating through `times_of`, not by iterating from `min` to `max`". Note 1< A(i)< 10^9, so iterating from `min` to `max` may cost a lot of time. Because of this, it seems `unordered_map` cannot work for it is unordered.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I'm not good at debugging, and you understand your code more than me...

Comment: I used your part of code to compute result. can you explain how it is computing in less time?

Comment: Cool, the map functions as a sparse array similar to what I was talking about with the variant of radix sort. Thus it can fit in memory.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Generally, iterating through `times_of` will skip elements that doesn't belong to `A`, so will be much faster if the array is sparse (for example, [1,2,100000]). But in your code, it seems that your input is quite simple, and it may have little improvement to change to iterating through `times_of`. Now it seems that your url is broken and I cannot see your code, thus don't know what happens to your code. I recommend you to (learn to) debug it by yourself.

Comment: I have done done all the changes and its working fine thank you folks

Comment: @Kenny its more about the lemma and less about sorting. I was unware about that lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a list of clusters on the first pass. Each has a collection of values, with a minimum and maximum value. These clusters could very well be stored in a segment tree (making it easy to merge in case they ever touch).

Loop through your N numbers, and for each number, either add it to an existing cluster (possibly triggering a merge), or create a new cluster. This may be easier if your clusters store min-1 and max+1.

Now you are done with the initial input of N numbers, and you have several clusters, all of which are likely to be of a reasonable size for radix sort.

However, you do not want to finish the radix sort. Generate the list of counts, then use this to count adjacent clusters. Loop through this, and every time the count decreases, you have found (difference) many of your final distinct sorted subsequences. (Using max+1 pays off again, because the guaranteed zero at the end means you don't have to add a special case after the loop.)

Comment: I may have misunderstood the queries. They are changing one of the inputs? I think this would still work with minor modification.